# Ionic Pro Montoring not working with Ionic DevApp

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view

I am working on an [ionic app](https://ionicframework.com/), and I would like to use [ionic pro monitoring](https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/monitoring/) for that, which works perfect if I open my app in a browser (`ionic serve --lab`) but it does not work for me if I open it with the [ionic dev app](https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/devapp/) or the [ionic view](https://ionicframework.com/pro/view) app?

Is this a bug or is ionic pro montoring not designed for that usage?

---

**UPDATE:**

I have these troubles only on ios, it works on android!

---

Thanks in advance for any advice